# Problema con JTextArea al imprimir

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente código que escribe un texto en el JtextArea, espera 3 segundos y lo borra. Mi problema es que el código no llega a escribir el primer texto.

```
bb.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

        pantalla.setText("Usted borrará la pantalla en 3 segundos!!");

        System.out.println(pantalla.getText());

        Date hora = new Date();
        hora.getTime();
        while(System.currentTimeMillis() < (hora.getTime() + 3000)){
        }
        if (pantalla.getText().equals(new String("Usted borrará la pantalla en 3 segundos!!"))){
        pantalla.setText("");
        System.out.print(1);
        }
        System.out.print("llegue");


    }
});
```

Comment: Te entra a ese método? Pon un punto de interrupción y nos lo dices, yo también pondría un try catch no sea que te de alguna excepción, aunque por el código que has puesto no lo parece

Comment: Si que entra, puse los prints para ver si imprimía correctamente y el primer print escribe el texto de la pantalla correctamente

Comment: sin embargo, no se muestra en la interfaz

Comment: Es probable que al intentar modificar algo del hilo principal desde otro no te deje (no se si lo haces desde otro hilo)

Comment: _Mi problema es que el código no llega a escribir el primer texto_ ¿Cuál es ese primer texto? ¿Acaso este: `pantalla.setText("");`? En el código no se ve que intentes escribir nada, si por escribir te refieres al método `setText()`

Comment: No se modifica desde ningún otro lugar, si ocurre un fallo antes de llegar al 2º setText si que lo imprime, pero si no, no lo hace.

Comment: El primer texto es pantalla.setText("Usted borrará la pantalla en 3 segundos!!");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los eventos del GUI se tratan en el Thread de "Event Dispatch", que también se encarga de repintar la pantalla. [Aquí tienes más información](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=8963)(en inglés, of course).

Dicho de otro modo, mientras se esté procesando el código asociado con el evento, no se refrescará la pantalla. Se refresca una vez que has salido, pero obviamente con el valor "" en `TextArea`.

Esto es lo que pasa cuando, por ejemplo, se intentá ejecutar una logica que tarda mucho tiempo y el GUI queda "congelado".

La solución es, tanto en tu caso como en el caso de GUI congelado, lanzar la lógica en un thread separado. Puede haber formas mejores (`ExecutorService` y similares), pero lo más rápido es:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               NombreSuperClase.this.pantalla.setText("Usted borrará la pantalla en 3 segundos!!");

               System.out.println(pantalla.getText());

               Date hora = new Date();
               hora.getTime();
               while(System.currentTimeMillis() < (hora.getTime() + 3000)){
                  synchronized(this) { //Evitar bucles vacíos!!!
                      this.wait(500);
                  }
                }

                if (pantalla.getText().equals(new String("Usted borrará la pantalla en 3 segundos!!"))){
                    pantalla.setText("");
                    System.out.print(1);
                 }
                 System.out.println("Llegué!");
             }
         }
         thread.start();
         System.out.print("thread lanzado");
      }
```

De paso, vuelvo a insistir que los bucles vacíos son muy mala cosa... mejor poner `wait` enmedio, aunque sean breves, de forma que no saturen la CPU (no hay mucho problema por un thread en un bucle infinito, pero si se hacen las cosas mal acabarás haciéndolo mal siempre y con 200 threads comiéndose el procesador).

Comment: Gracias por solucionarme el problema y por la aclaración de los bucles vaciíos